# populate data for new column in mysql with the use of existing rows for large table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'abc' with columns id,inTime, outTime.

current structure:

```
MyTable( outLocationStoreId,inTime,outTime )
```

sample data:

```
a8c17158-02b0-11e9-85bd-a5d592acb29f  2018-12-17 07:09:27  2018-12-18 10:35:33
4e8564dc-01c9-11e9-87db-dfbc2cdbb3ff  2018-12-16 15:49:16  2018-12-17 06:59:28
404414d8-0147-11e9-9179-29fa9411ff5b  2018-12-16 15:09:20  2018-12-16 15:28:27
```

I need to add a column nextInTime which will have the same value as InValue of above row.

```
New structure of  MyTable( outLocationStoreId,inTime,outTime,nextInTime )
```

sample data:

```
a8c17158-02b0-11e9-85bd-a5d592acb29f  2018-12-17 07:09:27  2018-12-18 10:35:33
4e8564dc-01c9-11e9-87db-dfbc2cdbb3ff  2018-12-16 15:49:16  2018-12-17 06:59:28   2018-12-17 07:09:27
404414d8-0147-11e9-9179-29fa9411ff5b  2018-12-16 15:09:20  2018-12-16 15:28:27   2018-12-16 15:49:16
```

I have to populate the data in the new column(nextInTime) for approximately 10 million records.
what's the best way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

We doesn't have relevant information such as 
- If your application doesn't have low activity period and cannot be put in maintenance
- your server load
- complexity of query to populate new query
- ...

I would tell you to do update by batch, may be about 1000 per batch, may be less or more.